# Multipart HttpListenerResponse without using chunked transfer

Tags: c#, server, httplistener

I have to integrate with an HTTP client over which I don't have control or influence.  It expects an HTTP response in the form of:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Server: server.localhost
Content-Type: multipart/x-mixed-replace;boundary=--boundary
 
--boundary
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Length: [length]
 
[data]
 
--boundary
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Length: [length]
 
[data]
 
[...]
```

I have an implementation that works with normal requests using `HttpListenerResponse` (i.e. where there is a `Content-Length` and sets the other values) but for this specific case I can't seem to get it to work because I cannot unset this header.

Is this possible with `HttpListenerResponse`?  It seems no matter what I do, I cannot unset the `Content-Length` header, and if I enable `HttpListenerResponse.SendChunked` the underlying implementation will add the requisite chunk headers (which I don't want).

Comment: The request has to ask for version otherwise default of server is used.  HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("URL");
            request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;

Comment: Hi @jdweng are you saying that I need to specify HTTP 1.0 and that will allow me to remove the content-length header?

Comment: Chunk mode is 1.1 while stream mode is 1.0.  When a client connect to a server there is a negotiation that is made to get common transfer mode.  The headers of the server webpage and the headers in the request are used.  When the client makes a request the server can accept the parameters,override the parameter, or when not specified use a default value.

Comment: So is it safe to say that when using HTTP 1.0 the underlying implementation knows not to send Content-Length?

Comment: Read 4.4 : https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#page-119